# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined - Splitting an array element (string) into array elements (more strings)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've recently started coding in JavaScript and am doing this for a course project. So, what I want to do is get spliced data (in this form: artist|album|year|genre|rating) from a textarea, then process it so that they are laid into tables after the form.

```
    <form name="viewform" enctype="text/plain">
        <table class="center" id="table0" name="table0">
    <!-- Here is the textarea and an onClick activated button -->
        </table>
        <table class="center" id="table1" name="table1">
            <tr>
                <th>Artist</th><th>Album</th><th>Year</th><th>Genre</th><th>Rating</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // viewScript() is for processing input from a textarea and setting it into HTML tables
        function viewScript() {
            var textArea = String(document.getElementById('textarea'));
            var arrayTextarea = textArea.split('\n'); // Every line becomes a string element in the array
            var arrayTextareaLength = arrayTextarea.length; // Count number of elements in arrayTextarea
            var table = document.getElementById('table1');
            var i, x;
            for (i=0; i <= arrayTextareaLength; i++) {
                var miniArray = arrayTextarea[i].split('|'); // Each string element in arrayTextarea becomes split into elements in miniArray. Each loop, miniArray changes to the next line
    /* Below is a loop to insert miniArray[i] into table1 */
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    </form>
```

Problem is in the line right after the for loop is opened. Developer's console tells me that it can't read property "split" of undefined. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `var textArea = String(document.getElementById('textarea').value);` You forgot to ask for the value of the text area - instead passing the element itself to the `String` function.

Comment: wr is the text area here

Comment: @enhzflep Although I can send data to my tables now, property "split" is still undefined. I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be a method.

Comment: @foxxy - If you edit your question such that it contains a 'working' example, you'll get better answers and make the question accessible to a wider audience. Some will see the problem just looking at the code, others would prefer to debug it. Not many are going to feel inclined to turn your snippet into something capable of being debugged - I sure don't. Consider reading and following the guidelines set out here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve :)